# JVM performance based on CPU type

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jvm, cpu, cpu-usage

I don't know if there is a straightforward answer to this. I have the specifications of different CPU types. For example, two instances,A and B. 
I want to run some simple java console application in A and B. Based on their specifications, can I assume the runtime of B after knowing the runtime on A?

Second questions is about the core numbers. So, can I assume the runtime of machine with i cores after knowing the result on the same machine with j cores?

Is there some approximations on this? The instances I am talking are Amazon EMR instances.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Based on their specifications, can I [estimate] the runtime of B after knowing the runtime on A?

The answer is No.  Or at least, not with any accuracy or confidence.  The performance of an application often depends on complex interactions between the algorithm's memory access patterns, memory caches and virtual memory hardware.  These are impossible to predict if you treat the application as a black box, and they can be difficult to model even if you understand what it is doing.  GC can also have the same kind of unpredictable behavior.

> Can I [estimate] the runtime of machine with i cores after knowing the result on the same machine with j cores?

The answer is No.  Application performance as you increase the number of cores is highly dependent on the way that you have designed and implemented your application.  In the best case you could linear speedup ... up to the limit of the platform's memory system.  In the worst case, you could get no speedup at all.

---

The only practical solution is to make a guesstimate ... then try out the various alternative platforms and see how your application performs on them.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if there is a straightforward answer to this. I have the specifications of different CPU types. For example, two instances,A and B. I want to run some simple java console application in A and B. Based on their specifications, can I assume the runtime of B after knowing the runtime on A?

You can guesitmate it by looking at the relative performance using a benchmark like PassMark.  However, you can see occasions where a system which is supposed to be faster is in fact slower.  This is only a very rough estimation.

> Second questions is about the core numbers. So, can I assume the runtime of machine with i cores after knowing the result on the same machine with j cores?

It is hihgly unlikely that say you have double the number of cores, you will get double the amount of performance.

- Your application may not scale by number of cores as your bottleneck might be another resources e.g. the network, or disk, or your program has too much sequential coding.
- When you have more cores, the speed of those cores tends to be slower on a sustained basis because the sockets can only produce so much heat.

> Is there some approximations on this? The instances I am talking are Amazon EMR instances.

If you are talking about virtual machines instead of real machines, it is even harder to estimate.  You might find that two virtual machines with the same spec don't perform the same. e.g. since your application might be running on different machines at different times, you may find it's performance varies even though the machine should have much the same spec.